# is mupdf pdf library really open-source GPL?

Tags: open-source, licensing, mupdf

I cannot find fitz.c file in mupdf folders. I can find fitz.h but, for example, I am not able to inspect the function

```
void fz_debug_obj(fz_obj *obj);
```

in detail, and other things I need.
Is it possible that some proprietary code is there so that using mupdf is not legal and they sue you when you make a derived work?

Comment: do you actually have a copy of the git repos? (from `git://git.ghostscript.com/mupdf.git`) it seems to me that you only have a prebuild library and headers; and the function `fz_debug_obj(fz_obj *obj)` you ask for is in `./fitz/obj_print.c`.

Comment: or without git: http://code.google.com/p/mupdf/downloads/detail?name=mupdf-0.9-source.tar.gz

Comment: ok, thank you @Dan D.,now answer so I can accept your answer. And, if you can, please take a look to my other question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7417994/mupdf-how-to-put-a-fz-pixmap-into-qt4-qpixmap

Comment: @DanD: Can you transfer your comments into an answer?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about licensing or legal issues, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274963/questions-about-licensing/274964#274964) and [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139804/can-licensing-questions-ever-be-on-topic) for details, and the [help] for more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[mupdf](http://www.mupdf.com/)'s full source is available via git at `git://git.ghostscript.com/mupdf.git` or in `tar.gz` format http://mupdf.googlecode.com/files/mupdf-0.9-source.tar.gz via http://code.google.com/p/mupdf/downloads/list.